# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined highstocks drilldown pie

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart, drilldown

I am getting an error all of the sudden for `drilldown` of `HighStocks` drilldown with PIE chart.

It runs perfectly over `Highchart.js` but when switched over to `Highstocks.js` it gives the error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Here is the JSFiddle with `Highcharts.js` and `HighStocks.js`, once again it works perfectly with `HighCharts.js`

https://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/boszwvgh/1/

Note: JSFiddle has a dummy implementation of what I am trying over my website.

[image: Screen showing console error on click of PIE, I am on Chrome]

Comment: your code works perfectly on IE11, FF Chrome and Edge (windows 10) whatever library you choose.

Comment: please check the screen I have updated in my question its giving me `console error` on click of PIE.

Comment: sorry, but only now I have had the possibility to understand where to look for the problem. I will try to fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: the problem is inside drilldown.js module when it tries to set f = f.lowerSeries = this.addSeries(a, !1);  It seems that lowerSeries  is missing. At the moment this is what I understood. Now the problem is: where is the lowerSeries ? And why changing from highcharts to highstock this value is missing?  Sorry for my little help.

Comment: I think that you can find information about this issue on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5778 it should be already fixed on developer brunch

Comment: @gaetanoM thanks for the help.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks for the Github link that sorts my issue. Thanks for the help as well.